# Escrow multisig output tx

Tags: multi-signature, escrow

Can someone please explain the third (Escrow) output transaction listed here:

https://blockchain.info/tx/09dd94f2c85262173da87a745a459007bb1eed6eeb6bfa238a0cd91a16cf7790?show_adv=true

What the exact intention and the expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the third output script:

```
OP_1 032487c2a32f7c8d57d2a93906a6457afd00697925b0e6e145d89af6d3bca33016
02308673d16987eaa010e540901cc6fe3695e758c19f46ce604e174dac315e685a OP_2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

Essentially it's saying that in order for the transaction to be valid, the input script (scriptSig) must provide signatures for one (OP_1) of the public keys listed above.

So both the owners of the private key associated with either `032487c2a32f7c8d57d2a93906a6457afd00697925b0e6e145d89af6d3bca33016` or `02308673d16987eaa010e540901cc6fe3695e758c19f46ce604e174dac315e685a` can validate that output.

This allows for scenarios where you need one of multiple entities (escrows) to validate a transaction before sending it off to someone.

Here's more info on `OP_CHECKMULTISIG` https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=38903.0

Comment: Hey Luca , 

Thanks for your answer, let me see if I got it right: 
if I want to explain that transaction in simple words
it means: 

$ 0.04 can be spend by 1EXoDusjGwvnjZUyKkxZ4UHEf77z6A5S4P (first one)
$ 0.04 can be spend by 1J2svn2GxYx9LPrpCLFikmzn9kkrXBrk8B (second one)
$ 0.09 can be spend by 1GUx7qydsHMWaMtF728HfSX1EQpQrZccdb or by 17rExRiMaJGgHPVuYjHL21mEhfzbRPRkui (the third one)
$ 54.34 can be spend by 17rExRiMaJGgHPVuYjHL21mEhfzbRPRkui (the 4th )

is it right interpretation ?

Comment: Yup, use BTC though since the values in dollars change ;)

Comment: Sure dollar sign is not so popular those days, 
so I am curious what would happen if both addresses will try to create an input transaction from that third one out tx, they both allowed to do that. Which one will actually spend the money ?

Comment: Here is follow up question:

http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21078/multisig-tx-1-out-of-2